# Why is Google showing the outdated contents of www.google.com/amp/s/MYAMPURL?

Tags: seo, google-search, amp

Recently I updated the contents of 100,000+ AMP pages of my server. However, when I search on my mobile, the results which Google shows are on the following URL:
https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.mywebpage.com/foo.html

which are completely different from:
https://amp.mywebpage.com/foo.html

How can I tell Google to make users to visit my website (at 'amp.mywebpage.com'), instead of showing the outdated contents of 'www.google.com'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a trick that was posted on the original StackExchange about how to force the cache to refresh: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36480283/is-it-possible-to-force-google-amp-html-pages-to-refresh

In your case, fire up a crawler/ bot and have it go to each page but with 'https://cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/' supplanting 'https://', e.g. https://cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/amp.mywebpage.com/foo.html for https://amp.mywebpage.com/foo.html